# Building my app but it say build failed with one error

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and building my app but it say build failed with one error plz help

```
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle' line: 32
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle'.
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > startup failed:
13:25:49.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle': 32: expecting '}', found '' @ line 32, column 1.
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   1 error
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
13:25:49.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Please post file C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle

Comment: you need to check this:
build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle': 32: expecting '}', found '' @ line 32, column 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I have solved above problem with help but now,i have got another error please help me resolve it also------------

Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_29zadyxffug4w4nfov6vkui3p$_run_closure3@3b916c58] on root project 'Happybirthday1' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
     Consult IDE log for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just missed a '}' in build.gradle file. Should be quite straightforward to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Missed "}" in the code

build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle': 32: expecting '}', found '' @ line 32, column 1.